# How to use LIKE and OR together in a Query

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

The following is my code  for altering a procedure which will search for a book name or book author:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchBook]

@Search_Var varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT * 
FROM Book 
WHERE 
BookName LIKE '%@Search_Var%' OR 
BookAuthor LIKE '%@Search_Var%'

END
```

I want it to display books by matching substring also i.e if book name is Fundamental Chemistry by typing chemistry also i should be able to get the result.
But the above code is not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate searched phrase like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchBook]
   @Search_Var VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * 
  FROM Book 
  WHERE 
    BookName LIKE '%' + @Search_Var + '%' 
    OR BookAuthor LIKE '%' + @Search_Var + '%';
END
```

Keep in mind that searching using `'%phrase%'` is not SARG-able and Query Optimizer won't use indexes if exists any.

Comment: Worked Fine, Thank You..!! :-)